# How to get MAX value using SOQL when there are more than 50,000 rows

Tags: soql, largedatavolumes, max

I would like to run this query:

```
SELECT MAX(Auto_Number__c) MaxNumber FROM Opportunity
```

But I am getting this error:

> System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

Because there are more than a `100,000` records.

Would adding a `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to the query still ensure I get the `MAX`?

```
SELECT MAX(Auto_Number__c) MaxNumber FROM Opportunity ORDER BY Auto_Number__c DESC LIMIT 1
```

But this give me:

> Ordered field must be grouped or aggregated: Auto_Number__c (129:16)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take out the MAX from your query:

```
SELECT Auto_Number__c FROM Opportunity ORDER BY Auto_Number__c DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I feel stupid..

Comment: @Robs We've all had moments like that, no need to feel bad about it 